# CSS attribute selector begin with

Tags: html, css

```css
[class*="grid-"]{
  border: 2px solid green;
}
[class^="grid-"]{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="grid-sm-1-3">one</div>
 <div class="grid-sm-1-3">two</div>
 <div class="other class grid-sm-1-3">three</div>
</div>
<div class="layout-grid-edit">do not match at all</div>
```

The issue is, if the element has multiple classes then the `class^="grid-="` doesn't seem to work, and I can't rely on `class*="grid-"` because it also matches something like `layout-grid-edit` which is not desired.

Comment: To be clear, which class(es) are you trying to style?

Comment: @TCharb I'm just targeting the classes starting with `grid-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced:

```
[class*="grid-"]{ 
}
```

With:

```
[class^="grid-"], 
[class*=" grid-"]{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@3zzy - Give this attribute selector a try below. This type of selector will be effective in targeting a class attribute beginning with the whole word `grid`, immediately followed by a hyphen:

```
[class|="grid"] { border: 2px solid green; }
```

See if this does the trick, and let me know.